# Retrieve the auto-increment value after inserting

Tags: android, android-intent, sqlite

This is the insert method I am using to insert some data into the db:

```
public long insertBooking(String userId,int roomId,Timestamp checkInTime, Timestamp checkOutTime){
    final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(USER_ID, userId);
    contentValues.put(ROOM_ID, roomId);
    contentValues.put(CHECK_IN, dateFormat.format(checkInTime));
    contentValues.put(CHECK_OUT, dateFormat.format(checkOutTime));

    return database.insert(MRM_BOOKING_DETAILS_TABLE, null, contentValues);

}
```

The **MRM_BOOKING_DETAILS** table has got an auto-increment field called **booking_id**. After inserting a new row, the value of this column is incremented by 1. Is it possible to return the **booking_id** of the row once the insertion is completed in the above method itself without writing a separate select query?

Or, do I have to write a separate SQL Select query to return that **booking_id** of that newly inserted row?

Comment: AFAIK, what the insertBooking method returns is the inserted ID.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**long insertId =  database.insert(MRM_BOOKING_DETAILS_TABLE, null, contentValues);**
 this line itself returns the booking_id of the inserted row...